# Necessary to pass bump for PDA in the instruction data when using Anchor?

Tags: anchor, pda, bump

I've noticed many programs on Solana written with Anchor asks for the `bump` in the instruction data, then checks it inside the `#account` macro with `bump = bump`.

I've tried omitting the caller-supplied `bump` parameter, using just `#[account(seeds = [...], bump)]` and passing a non-canonical PDA address, and Anchor correctly throws an error `Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`.

So it seems like having the caller-supplied `bump` makes no difference to checking if the PDA is canonical. Furthermore you can always retrieve the canonical bump via `ctx.bumps.get("<account>")`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so got an answer from the man/myth/legend Armani:

1. Never pass bump via instruction data
2. `init` should not specify a bump explicitly
3. Recommended: store `bump` in PDA
4. Recommended: subsequent use of seeds should always specify a `bump` from the account data, ie `bump = account.bump` constraint

(3)/(4) are recommended but not necessary since you can still use a naked `bump` constraint, but less efficient since `find_program_address` needs to be invoked + validated.

Comment: Richard, 
1. Why should we store bump in PDA ?
2. Number (4) is unclear to me

Comment: because it is faster and deterministic to derive the PDA when you provide the bump. If you don't provide the bump, the lib will loop trying to "find" the PDA with different bumps (255->0), so the computation units can vary depending on the seeds you use. E.g. you're using user account as seed and not storing bump: consequence: the instruction has different cost depending on the user account (more or less tries to find the first PDA), so the instruction can fail for some (all CPU budget consumed) and work for others